# VisualBasic Make and Model ComboBox

Tags: makefile, combobox, model

My goal is to have this program able to tell which make is selected and offer a list of models based on that. However, when I click the ComboBox, execute the program, and select a Make, I am not getting any selections in my Model ComboBox. Can anyone help me with this? Here is my source code:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

Private Sub ButtonExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExit.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Initialize the text property of the three Combo Boxes to a NULL string
    ComboBoxMake.Text = ""
    ComboBoxModel.Text = ""
    ComboBoxColor.Text = ""
    'Add a number of cars to the "Make" ComboBox.
    ComboBoxMake.Items.Add("Honda")
    ComboBoxMake.Items.Add("Toyota")
    ComboBoxMake.Items.Add("Ford")
    ComboBoxMake.Items.Add("Lexus")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBoxMake_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxMake.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim SelectedItem As String
    SelectedItem = CStr(ComboBoxMake.SelectedItem()) 'Return the selected item from the ComboBox
    MessageBox.Show(SelectedItem) 'Display the selected item
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBoxModel_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxModel.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim SelectedItem As String
    SelectedItem = CStr(ComboBoxMake.SelectedItem()) ' Return the selected item from the ComboBox
    If SelectedItem = "Honda" Then
        ComboBoxModel.Text = "" 'Initialize the text property to a NULL string
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Clear()
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Add("Accord")
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Add("Civic")
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Add("CRV")
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Add("Pilot")
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Add("Odyssey")
    ElseIf SelectedItem = "Toyota" Then
        ComboBoxModel.Text = "" 'Initialize the text property to a NULL string
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Clear()
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Add("Camrey")
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Add("Avalon")
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Add("4Runner")
    Else
        ComboBoxModel.Items.Add("Not Available")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using double equals when comparing the String values.

Comment: I tried and it gave me an error, I don't know what I'm doing wrong